# add click event to all li which has id - using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to add the click event to all the `li's` inside a div which has id to the li.

The following script changes for all the li's:

```
   <ul>
    <li>
    <h4>My Header</h4></li>
    <li id="myli1">My li 1</li>
    <li id="myli2">My li 2</li></ul>


        $("#mydiv li").live('click', function(e) {
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
          });
```

I need to add the click events for only the li which has the id attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

```
    $("#mydiv li[id]").live('click', function(e) {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the solution of @ Greg or you can select the types of Id's. see [jQuery Selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)

```
$("#mydiv li[id^='myli']").live('click', function(e) {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```